# MongoEngine: Limiting number of responses from DBRef

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a document with around 7k DBRefs in one field to other objects. I want to limit the number of the objects coming back when I query the DBRef field but I cannot find an obvious way of doing it.

```
project = Project.objects.find({'id': 1})
users = project.users[:10]
```

On line 2 MongoEngine performs a query to retrieve ALL the users not just the first 10. What can I do to limit the query to only retrieve the first 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *users = project.users[:10],*

This operation is a client side operation, which is performed on the `users` array that has all the `7k DBRefs` values returned by `mongodb`.

> *What can I do to limit the query to only retrieve the first 10?*

You need to include a `projection` operation to just select the first `10` elements in the `users` array.

```
Project.objects.find({"id": 1},{"users":{"$slice":10}})
```

The syntax in `MongoEngine`:

```
Project.objects(id=1).fields(slice__users[0,10])
```

Comment: In MongoEngine you need to perform `Project.objects(id=1).fields(slice__users[0,10]).first()`

Comment: Thanks for the info.Have updated my answer w.r.t your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is no way to return a portion of one field.  You can pick and choose what fields you are returning, but there is no way to specify a portion of one field.